# Changing the default title of confirm() in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to modify the title of the message box the confirm() function opens in JavaScript?

I could create a modal popup box, but I would like to do this as minimalistic as possible.
I would like to do something like this:

```
confirm("This is the content of the message box", "Modified title");
```

The default title in Internet Explorer is "Windows Internet Explorer" and in Firefox it's "[JavaScript-program]." Not very informative. Though I can understand from a browser security stand point that you shouldn't be able to do this.

Answer (score 92, accepted):

This is not possible, as you say, from a security stand point. The only way you could simulate it, is by creating a modeless dialog window.

There are many third-party javascript-plugins that you could use to fake this effect so you do not have to write all that code.

Comment: Bootstrap.CSS has some nice modals

Answer (score 10):

YES YOU CAN do it!! It's a little tricky way ; )  (it almost works on ios)

```
var iframe = document.createElement("IFRAME");
iframe.setAttribute("src", 'data:text/plain,');
document.documentElement.appendChild(iframe);
if(window.frames[0].window.confirm("Are you sure?")){
    // what to do if answer "YES"
}else{
    // what to do if answer "NO"
}
```

Enjoy it!

Comment: Initially this created an error. Then, after placing the `if` block in a timeout, it produced the same result in Firefox. Doesn't work in Chrome. http://jsfiddle.net/pzd9pmeu/

Comment: this changes the title to "An embedded page on this webpage says:"

Comment: Aw man, that's a nasty hack.

I'm not saying there's anything wrong with that.

But that has to go right up there with some of the nastiest hacks I've seen so far.

You know- kudos for the can do spirit!

Answer (score 5):

Not possible.  You can however use a third party javascript library that emulates a popup window, and it will probably look better as well and be less intrusive.

Answer (score 3):

You can always use a hidden div and use javascript to "popup" the div and have buttons that are like yes and or no. Pretty easy stuff to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can't unfortunately. The only way is to simulate this with a window.open call.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the confirm() dialog then...  easy to use a custom dialog from prototype/scriptaculous, YUI, jQuery ... there's plenty out there.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is not possible for alert(), so I guess it is not possible for confirm either. Reason is security: it is not allowed for you to change it so you wouldn't present yourself as some system process or something.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is impossible to modify the title of it. If you still want to have your own title, you can try to use other pop-up windows instead.