# how to change the title of the confirmation in asp

Tags: asp.net, title

I have added a confirmation dialog before deleting an item in asp.net web page.
Here's my coding.

```
OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this Contact Record?');"
```

It gives the default title as **"The page at local host:49456 says:"**
I need to change that default title of this dialog box.My default browser is Google chrome.
Can somebody help me???
Thanx in advance.

Comment: duplicate -http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43955/changing-the-default-title-of-confirm-in-javascript

Answer (score 0):

Give the Header needed like this.

```
   OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this Contact Record?','Your Title');
```

Answer (score 0):

note: when tweaking page title - can't change it here if the aspx page sets it to "". so, in the .aspx page set it to something other than empty string; e.g.:

```
  Page.Title = "Some New Title";
```