# Simple jquery alert box like of javascript which has a option to edit the title?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using the Javascript alert box:

```
function shareConfirm() {
    if(!confirm('Are you sure want to unshare?')) return false;
}
```

However, the title give the URL says and the alert box but I want to edit the title. It turns out javascript title can't be edited. So I best bet is to use jquery simple alert box with the same css as the custom javascript alert box. How can I do that?

Comment: System alerts can't have the title edited you'll need a custom alert. http://labs.abeautifulsite.net/archived/jquery-alerts/demo/

Comment: You should see this post : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43955/changing-the-default-title-of-confirm-in-javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would you mind to use jQueryUI ? Then solving your problem will be easy as butter :)

Step 1:
    Include jQueryUI in ur page.

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Step 2:
    Create a div. The text in this div will display as alert. You need to hide this div in `$(document).ready()`

```
<div id='myAlertbox'></div>
```

Step 3:
Here you go:

```
$("#myAlertbox").html('Are you sure want to unshare?');
$("#myAlertbox").dialog({
    title: "yourRequiredTitleHere",
modal: true,
buttons : [{
    text : "Ok",
    click : function() {
            $(this).dialog("close");
            //You can do whatever you want here.
    }
    }],
});
```

Comment: Apparently, easy as butter. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible, as you say, from a security stand point. The only way you could simulate it, is by creating a modeless dialog window.

Answer (score -1):

the style of confirm() and alert() boxes depend on the browser and operating system. therefore it will be a nearly impossible to create a css for jquery alert boxes to match each browser/os combination