# Customizing JavaScript confirmation dialog boxes?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$('#confirm_event').click(function(e){
    var x = $('#function_name').val();
    return confirm('Are you sure you want to submit: ')
})
```

[image]

While this generates the above, I'd like to replace "title bar text" and include var x value in the return confirm message. I tried several ways but returns undefined value or doesn't work at all. How do I customize the dialog box?

Comment: Hey, Snowden is learning javascript.

Comment: In Moscow, they "get things done" in the client side! :)

Comment: I have added a working example to the original question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1905289/how-to-edit-a-javascript-alert-box-title/50252295#50252295) using jqueryui-dialog if anyone interested.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You  cannot change the default dialog's title. Go for any [Jquery Ui dialog plugin.](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/)

Or some other third party dialog [plugins.](http://jquerybyexample.blogspot.in/2012/12/10-jquery-modal-dialog-boxes-plugins.html)

Prefer to read :[Changing the default title of confirm() in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43955/changing-the-default-title-of-confirm-in-javascript)

I prefer to use Jquery Ui dialog :)

Comment: I'm starting to like jQuery Impromptu. Thank you for the reference.

Answer (score 1):

Well You can not change look of the window's default alert here what you can do.

Use **[`jAlert jQuery Plugin`](http://dochoffiday.com/Professional/jalert-a-jquery-ui-alert-confirm-replacement)** that will let user see custom alert box.

Also **[`Take a Look`](http://labs.abeautifulsite.net/archived/jquery-alerts/demo/)**