# how to remove or change the popup automatic message

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery-ui

I display a popup to ask confirmation of delete a record, the popup displays but with a "system message" like "the page at the address mywebsite show:" follows by my message "are you sure ....".

I want to display only my message 'Are you sure ?'Not the message 'the page at the address mywebsite show:' just above my message.

How can do this please ?
Thank in advance.

```
<a href="php/Delete.php5?" onClick="return confirm('Are your sure ?');"><img src="images/Cancel16x16.png"></a>
```

Comment: Make your question clerer

Comment: Just remove the `onClick`?

Comment: it displays 'The page at the address mywebsite show: Are you sure ?'. I want it displays just 'Are you sure ?'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **Title** for the JavaScript `confirm()` is unfortunately unchangeable (See this SO question: [Changing the default title of confirm() in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43955/changing-the-default-title-of-confirm-in-javascript)) , That's the same for the changing any of the style & looks for it too.

To allow you to use common scripts such as callbacks, change of text or event changes etc. on JavaScript `confirm()`s. These better left for helpers such as [jQuery UI Dialog](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/) (There are many others too) which uses `<div>`s to mimic the `confirm()` behaviour and provide much, much more control for a Web Developer.

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $( "#userconfirm" ).on('click', function() {
           $('#dialog').dialog({ 
                title: "Your new Title"
           });
    });
</script>  

<a href="php/Delete.php5?" id="userconfirm">
   <img src="images/Cancel16x16.png">
</a>

<div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog">
     <p>Are you sure?</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could able to use [jquery-ui](/questions/tagged/jquery-ui) modal to perform this message instead of javascript's `confirm()`.

The following link shows you how to get it from the official documenation of jquery-ui: http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-confirmation

**Edit**
You are able to checkout this demo which is a modification from the official docs example:
http://jsbin.com/iBApeKe/2/

Answer (score 0):

You can use [jquery ui dialog](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/) for such purposes

Comment: @NhuPhung I was earlier for 3 seconds. You're welcome