# how can we change confirm button text in from OK ,Cancel To YES , NO, Cancel

Tags: javascript

dialog box by MessageBox, but MessageBoxButton only provide option for button as OK, Cancel. How to change it to YES, NO ,Cancel button?how can we change confirm button text in from OK ,Cancel To YES , NO, Cancel

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43955/changing-the-default-title-of-confirm-in-javascript

Comment: What I can use ? Please suggest